# upload received ssl data to distributed servers

Tags: networking, ssl, wireshark

I am doing the network traffic analysis for a live camera device from a Chinese company which allows to view the real time video from ios6 app.

172.17.200.2 is the IP of the ios device.And the vendor of the camera claims that they dont store the video on their server.

However, the network traffic analysis shows that the app will upload exactly the same amount of data to different servers after it receives from one server.

Does it mean that they are storing the video data to their servers?

[image]

Comment: No, it only means that roughly the same amount of data is uploaded to different servers. I am not trying to be picky here. But there is little sense in drawing conclusions without having real evidence. There can be different explanations.